# What is this drill bit?

Tags: drill-bits

I've spent much time searching.  Can someone tell me what this bit is used for?  Here are photos:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Every thread I chase returns to only one item, currently listed on [eBay as a Roberts Company 3 bit fly cutter with pilot](https://www.ebay.com/itm/circle-metal-ROBERT-CLARK-co-3-DRILL-BIT-adjustable-fly-cutter-pilot-tool-shop-/112143312579). The one on eBay has a solid rod in place of the drill bit, but that's trivial.

All indications are that it's designed to cut holes in metal.

[image: Fly cutter]

The one in the photo may have a taper, allowing it to be inserted directly into a matching spindle.